# java.lang.nullPointerException registering button

Tags: nullpointerexception

I added the following to connect the register page of my program to my database but receive the error java.lang.nullPointerException whenever I press the register button to test making an account. I think the problem is the getText have to be getPassword instead but I receive a method when I do that. Anyone have any ideas?

```
register = new JButton("Register");
    register.setBackground(Color.black);
    register.setForeground(Color.white);
    register.setBounds(250, 12, 120, 30);
    register.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent reg) {
            if (firstName.getText().equals("") || lastName.getText().equals("") || age.getText().equals("") || user.getText().equals("") || pass.getText().equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input Data.\nPlease Try Agian.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            try{
                String sql = "INSERT INTO Users (ID, First Name, Last Name, Age, Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ps.setInt(1, 0);
                    ps.setString(2, firstname.getText());
                    ps.setString(3, lastname.getText());
                    ps.setString(4, age.getText());
                    ps.setString(5, user.getText());
                    ps.setString(6, pass.getText());
                    ps.execute();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registration Successful!/nYou can now log into the database.");
            }catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        finally {
            try{
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
            }catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: If you are using `JTextField`, the method for get the chars from that field must be definitely `getPassword()`, since getText is deprecated!

Comment: @sgmart, Wouldn't he use `JPasswordField`?

Comment: i used jpasswordfield since it make more sense to have the password hidden when typed

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc for JTextField's default constructor:

> public JTextField()
>
> Constructs a new TextField. A default model is created, the initial string is null, and the number of columns is set to 0.

So, if the user doesn't fill in `firstName`, `firstName.getText() == null`, and the NPE is thrown.

You could improve this class by doing a few things:

1. Subclass `AbstractAction` and use it with your button; the `AbstractAction` can also be used in menus too.
2. Put a `DocumentListener` on the text and password fields to enable or disable the abstract action, which also enables and disables the button.
3. Have all the actual work done in a controller class; move the database code out of the Swing class.  Can you imagine writing to the database or checking user info from a non-UI class?  Then don't do it here.
4. Never store a password (or a credit card number) in a database.  Always store a salted hash instead.
5. Use Java 7 try-with-resources for the `PreparedStatement`.  Watch out; if the first `close` statement in your finally block throws, the second never executes; you would need to wrap `rs.close()` in a try-catch block.  But try-with-resources makes that irrelevant. By the way, from the Javadoc for the close method,

> When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.

Comment: the other TextFields are working fine when I link the getText but its just ps.setString(6, pass.getText()); that is giving me problems. the database is currently stored on my computer but im going to add a custom binary format to it later.

Comment: As @sgmart wrote, use `getPassword()` instead.

Comment: `getPassword()` returns a `char[]`, not a `String`.  It is a bad idea for a password to be stored in an object; when an object is ready to be discarded by the JVM, the garbage collector may not dispose of it right away.  Somebody who can analyze the memory of the computer might notice the password while it's waiting for disposal.  Look at the Javadoc; it tells you that it's best to zero out the `char[]` as soon as possible so no one can peak at it.